# Why does the for loop print out a string in this situation

Tags: python

I'd like to know the reason why any string given is printed out on the code below.
I do understand that a for loop could print out, lets say,
numbers from 0 to 10 but I can't figure out why and how it would print a string

```
expr = str(input('Write your expression'))                                                                                               
for simb in expr:
    print(simb)
```

Comment: Strings are iterable in Python. When you put it in a `for` loop it *iterates* over the string, taking each character and putting in the variable `simb`, which you then print. The same thing happens if you put a list in a for loop, i.e. `for el in ['a', 'b', 'c']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a `for` loop on a string makes it iterate over **EVERY** character of that string.
If you want to print your `expr`, then try just printing the name `expr` like so: `print(expr)`